# Sqlalchemy Query Succeeds in Sublime Text IDE but fails when executed from the command line

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Hey everyone. I'm building an Albums DB application for a college project using sqlalchemy and pyqt (as both are libraries I'd like to gain a little experience with), all written in Python 3.
My IDE of choice is Sublime 3 and my database server is Mariadb running on an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit variant (Elementary OS).

The problem I'm having is quiet strange and I don't know where to go from here (I actually thought I was nearly finished, duh!).

If I execute the application from inside Sublime (f7) then the program functions the way I would expect with all queries returning the desired values (hence why I thought I was nearly done).
However, If I make the script executable and execute it from the command line or from inside another IDE (Geany in this case) the thing falls apart but only when trying to make certain queries based on filtering arguments provided by user input. Queries elsewhere in the program succeed e.g. Songs.query.all() will return all songs in the DB.

The code below is a snippet of where the error occurs in the 'Read' section of the application. 'table' refers to a Table object (Songs, Albums or Artists) and the filter column & clause refer to string arguments entered by the user.

```
    elif function == 'Read':

        # Debug Print - Display Details
        print('Table is ' + str(table))
        print('Clause is ' + clause)
        # Carry out the Query - Should only return 1 match - Fails Here
        r = table.query.filter(
            getattr(table, column.lower()) == clause).one()

        if self.db == 'Songs':

            # Query Corresponding Album & Artist
            al = Albums.query.get(int(r.album_id))
            ar = Artists.query.get(int(r.artist_id))

            headers = 'Name;Artist;Album;Track Number;Genre'
            data = [r.name, ar.name, al.name,
                    r.track_num, r.genre]
```

My Models are as follows:

```
    class Artists(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'artists'

        artist_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(30))

        albums = relationship(
            'Albums', backref='artists', cascade='all, delete-orphan')
        songs = relationship(
             'Songs', backref='artists', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

    class Albums(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'albums'

        album_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
        artist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('artists.artist_id'))
        created_on = Column(
            DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

        songs = relationship(
            "Songs", backref="albums", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    class Songs(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'songs'

        song_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(50))
        track_num = Column(Integer)
        genre = Column(String(30))
        created_on = Column(
            DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

        album_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('albums.album_id'))
        artist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('artists.artist_id'))
```

The Error when trying to match a song that is present in the DB is :

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 3") [SQL: 'SELECT songs.song_id AS songs_song_id, songs.name AS songs_name, songs.track_num AS songs_track_num, songs.genre AS songs_genre, songs.created_on AS songs_created_on, songs.album_id AS songs_album_id, songs.artist_id AS songs_artist_id \nFROM songs \nWHERE songs.name = %s'] [parameters: ('WHAT WENT DOWN',)]

Any help on this issue would be wonderful, and if there is any additional information needed I'll be more than happy to provide. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about the syntax of `%s` as a bind parameter. If I'm not mistaken, MySQL syntax uses `?` for positional and `:name` for keyword bind params. `%s` is what the `psycopg2` library uses because it does its own statement preparation. Your engine configuration is not shown here.

As for the difference between Sublime and running from console, look for (a) any potential difference in the Python interpreter being used and (b) any potential difference in imports due to `PYTHONPATH` issues.

Comment: It was the interpreter! I feel like such a douche. Sublime was executing in 2.7 and i was trying to force it to use 3. Thanks a bunch Jason, really appreciate it.